# Python - TypeError '>' not supported between instances of dict_values and int

Tags: python, mapreduce

I am getting the above error in the following code

''

```
cust_list = []
result = []   
temp_cust_list = []
hold_val = 0
hold_cust_id = ''

for key,dict_value in cust_dictionary.items():
    rest_value = cust_dictionary.values()
    for key in cust_dictionary.keys():
        month_country_key, cust_id_key = key.split(';') 
    if month_country_key in result:
        if rest_value == hold_val:
            temp_cust_list.append(cust_id_key)
        elif rest_value >  hold_val:
           temp_cust_list = ()
           hold_val == rest_val
    else:
          result.append(month_country_key)
          hold_val == value
          if len(result) > 1:
              result.append(temp_cust_list)
              temp_cust_list = []
              temp_cust_list.append(cust_id_key)
          
print(temp_cust_list)
```

``

### My dict looks like this:
month country  custid  sales
|01,Australia;12386 68.0   |

### |01,Australia;12415 103.68 |

|01,Australia:13456 03.68 |

And I am trying to find the most sales per month/country combination and print the month, country followed by the customer id. like this: Month,Country:CustomerID. Any ties  list all customers with commas in between. I am gettign the type error and not sure what I need to do I ahve tried moving the dict value to another field but that doesn't work either.

Comment: `rest_value` is not a single value, it's a sequence of values.

Answer (score 0):

`rest_value` is a list originating from `cust_dictionary.values()`

therefore the operator `>` will not work here.

Comment: So would I have to search using key or partial key and compare value retrieved or how would I accomplish finding the greatest  amount for the given month country combo?

Comment: Could you share what the `cust_dictionary` looks like? Then I can suggest a working code.

Comment: Sure Cust_dictionary looks like this - key is month, country;Customer Id and the key is sales_amt. so the data looks like this: '                    
 {'01','Australia';'123456':750.00                                            '01','Australia';'124456':550.00                                              
 1','Australia';'123556':750.00

Comment: So in the above your expected output would be: `01,Australia:123556`

Comment: How does it handle duplicates? Because if  there are multiple customer ids with the top amount I need to display them both.

Comment: expected output from above would be 01,Australia:123456,123556 since both have amount of 750.00

Comment: I'm sorry but I am lost. Can you please add a properly formatted python dictionary in your question and a properly formatted output.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
max_sales = 0
max_record = []

for record, sales in cust_dictionary.items():

    if sales > max_sales:
        max_sales = sales
        max_record = [record]
    elif sales == max_sales:
        max_record.append(record)
    else:
        pass

print(max_record, max_sales)
```